# How do compilers used precompiled libraries?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation

I don't understand how compilers know what to do if they're using precompiled libraries. For instance, suppose my program is

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{
   std::vector<int> V = {1, 69, 111}; 
   for (std::vector<int>::iterator it(V.begin()), offend(V.end()); it != offend; ++it) 
         std::cout << *it << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Clearly `std::vector` is overkill for that simple program. But how does the compiler know that unless it knows how `std::vector` is implemented in the C++ language?

Comment: You're probably asking about a Linker.  See if reading up on that helps you find what you're asking. :) [Linker wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))

Comment: Are you familiar with statically linked and dynamically linked libraries? Getting information on those topics may clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably no "precompiled binaries" involved in your example. However you are using the [standard C++ library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) (which provides the operations on `cout` and headers like `<vector>`); read more about software [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) (and indeed, the `libstdc++.so` shared library on Linux is in compiled binary form).

You have a `#include <vector>` then you are instanciating a [C++ template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29) using `std::vector<int>` so the compiler is defining some classes & functions (needed by `std::vector<int>`) and emitting the relevant code.

Read more about [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), e.g. [Levine's book on *Linkers & loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linkers/); the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) also has a chapter on [template instantiation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html)

BTW, you might look inside the [preprocessed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) form of your program (supposedly in file `yoursource.cc`). If using *GCC* compile that source code with 
 `g++ -Wall -C -E yoursource.cc > yoursource.ii` then use an editor or a pager to look inside the (quite large) `yoursource.ii` generated file, which is quite similar to what the compiler is actually "seeing"

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're thinking of [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx). Libraries consists of a set of object files that were previously compiled or assembled. As mentioned, templates are a form of source code that are included as headers.

Comment: I don't think that the OP was thinking of precompiled headers.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - but in the OP's example, it's using vector and iostream, which are headers.

Comment: Indeed the OP use headers, but is probably not thinking of precompiling them. He is probably not entirely understanding what the preprocessor is actually doing. I understand that "precompiled libraries" refer to `libstdc++.so`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - the key term here is precompiled. I don't know where the OP read about the term precompiled, but it makes more sense if it's a reference to headers and not to libraries.